# how the underlying data structure of BigTable is implemented?

Tags: c++, bigtable

I am learning about SSTABLE and MVCC and have decided to read the BigTable paper. However, the data model of BigTable seems quite abstract, so I have decided to implement a small prototype using C++.
I designed some data structures, but there seems to be some redundancy. Is this design correct?

```
// A struct that represents a cell in the Bigtable
struct Cell {
    string value; // The value of the cell
    int64_t timestamp; // The timestamp of the cell
};

// A struct that represents a column family in the Bigtable
struct ColumnFamily {
    string name; // The name of the column family
    map<string, Cell> cells; // A map from column keys to cells
};

// A struct that represents a row in the Bigtable
struct Row {
    string RowKey; // The key of the row
    vector<ColumnFamily> column_families; // A vector of column families in the row
};

class table {
    string table_name;
    vector<Row> rows_;
};
```

Comment: I never heared of it (but I assume you refer to [google's bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/bigtable/latest). What you are looking at there is the public facing API. An API shows nothing, or at least it should not show, about the the internal design. Which I am sure is not even close to your approach, insertion/lookup of data would be way too slow and take more memory then needed. My most naive expectations would include treelike datastructures, but I suspect there might even be more complex datastructures in play to guarantee performance.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer Yes, Google bigtable is not open source. Actually, I’m curious about how the main structure of bigtable is designed because it is logically a table structure. I’m just writing a demo and don’t pursue performance. I just need the outline of the storage structure. I’m curious whether similar databases like bigtable are row-oriented or column-oriented.

Comment: Probably neither, but we will never know all the details. Just google around a bit on big table and performance and you will find this [bigtable/docs/performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance). And from that it seems row oriented.  And more here [schema design](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) where it states a close relation to the actual queries. My advice when you are curious, just look around for documentation and start reading that ;) I guess that's all the help I can give you now.

Comment: The storage for Google Bigtable is Colossus. YouTube has an excellent video on [Colossus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4WC_6SzBz4). Another item to investigate is Bigtable sharded "tablets". Bigtable tables are sparse. That means if a column does not have data it does not take space in the table. Column families are optional. Your design does not include those design items but is a good start. Tip: you can download the Bigtable emulator and run it in a container. If you get stuck, post another question and I will show you how.

Comment: @John Hanley this is beyond my learning scope. However, this is a good suggestion. The bad news is that Google requires the use of a debit card. So I have not been able to run Bigtable.